# Fixng unused formal parameter warnings without making an abstract class

Tags: c++

I have a base class and it has virtual functions. The issue is that, the base is allowed to be instanced, but that means that all of its functions need a definition. This causes the compiler to warn me about unused parameters. What can I do to properly get rid of these warnings without making pure virtual functions and making it an abstract class?

example:

```
class Foo {
public:
virtual void bar(int x) {} //unused formal parameter int x
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @PigBen: Then they wouldn't be virtual methods that can be invoked through pointer-to-base.

Comment: It is a code smell.  Why isn't the virtual function pure?  =0.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth:  Yeah, I get that.  But what I was implying was a design flaw.  I can't be sure since he didn't provide actual code, but I have serious doubts that there is a good reason to do what he is doing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usual solution is:

```
virtual void bar(int x) { (void)x; }
```

or:

```
virtual void bar(int) {}
```

This prevents the compiler from whinging.  Note that this technique isn't restricted to virtual member functions; it should work for any function where you don't intend to use one or more arguments.

On an unrelated note; an instantiable base class with empty member-function definitions doesn't sound like a very good idea; are you sure that you wouldn't be better off just making it abstract?

Comment: Well, it's the base class for Widgets for my GUI API and I use it as the root widget to hold all the other widgets. It shouldn't really be used, but it is at the discretion of the user.

Comment: @Milo: You should consider *why* the user would do such a thing, if it has empty function definitions.

Comment: @Milo: That's screaming out to be abstract.  If you have no intention of it being instantiable, and if it doesn't really make any sense for it to be instantiable, then prevent the user from instantiating it.  Doing so also allows you to declare certain member functions as pure-virtual, which documents your intentions more clearly.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth One thing, what if a widget does not need to implement allll the virtual functions, like, a button might not handle onKeyDown().

Comment: @Milo: Obviously, only the member functions that the client *must* instantiate should be pure-virtual.

Comment: @Milo: Then you need to refactor. If a function is not *required* to be implemented to be part of an interface, then what is it doing in the interface? If it makes sense to say "this can be nothing", then just make it not-pure. In other words: Must be part of the interface and null implementation doesn't make sense -> pure virtual, Must be part of the interface and null implementation makes sense -> virtual, not a necessary aspect of the interface: remove the function.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a problem in using the absolutely most obvious solution?

```
class Foo {
public:
  virtual void bar(int) {}
};
```

Just remove the parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, an alternative method is:

```
virtual void bar(int /*x*/) {}
```